# How to check if the user is eligible to view the content in objectURL?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

Is there a way to authenticate the user before he could open a specific `Bucket` link? For example, before a user could open:

```
https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/test-bucket-pcloud/folder-1/Talk+with+code+by+PCbots.png?X-Amz-Date=20160114T061130Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Signature=8749e1159d&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAIL2CZ6LKSDT2X5PQ/20160114/us-west-2/s3/aws4_request&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=Host&x-amz-security-token=Ag3LQF
```

I need to check if he has access to view the contents of a bucket named `test-bucket-pcloud`. Is it possible?

```
    $cmd = $s3Client->getCommand('GetObject', [
            'Bucket' => 'test-bucket-pcloud',
            'Key'    => 'testfile.txt'
    ]);
    $request = $s3Client->createPresignedRequest($cmd, '+20 minutes');
    $presignedUrl = (string) $request->getUri();
    // Accessible by any user!
```

Comment: Your logic seems reversed -- don't sign the URL and provide it to the user until after authenticating the user and verifying the user's authorization to access the file.  Once it's created, it's usable to do whatever action is authorized, by whoever, wherever.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Okay. But even you would be able to access the link that has been provided to the authenticated user!?

Comment: Yes, that's true, which is why I always use HTTPS, and typically issue signed URLs  in the `Location:` header with a `302 Found` HTTP redirect of the request from an authorized user... and give the signed URL a very short expiration time, since the expiration time is only checked at the beginning of the download (and therefore you don't have to accommodate the speed of the downloader's Internet connection when choosing an expiration time).  There may be another somewhat unconventional approach to further restrict usability of signed URLs by others, which is something I am investigating...